# UIPickerView reloadcomponent not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

Im making an app that uses a picker view. When the app loads, the picker view is given initial options. I then wish to change these options by changing the array used in the delegate and then calling the reloadcomponent method in an IBAction triggered by a button press. When i do this, nothing happens. The initial choices are still there. Delegate and dateSource are both set to files owner. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Below is the code used in the IBAction (the NSLog shows that the array is getting changed correctly):

NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Elec Beat 1",@"Elec Beat 2",@"Elec Beat 3",@"Elec Beat 4",@"Elec Beat 5",nil];

```
[pickerChoices removeAllObjects];
[PickerChoices addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
[pickerView reloadComponent:0];
packSelect = 1;

NSLog(@"%@",pickerChoices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented methods of UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerDataSource?